# "include" does not work in "if / else" PHP

Tags: php, cookies, header, include, sentence

I'm trying to include the header for logged in users if they have an active session, if not, show the header for unregistered users! But the problem is that this code does not work, in the browser inspector does not appear any code other than  , and the screen is all white.
This code is in index.php

```
<?php
include("db.php");
if (isset($_COOKIE["login"]) && isset($_COOKIE["login2"])) {
        $user_id = $_COOKIE["id"];
        $email = $_COOKIE["login"];
        $password = $_COOKIE["login2"];
        $verify = mysqli_query($connect, "SELECT * FROM users WHERE email='$email' AND password='$password'");
        if (mysqli_num_rows($verify)>=1) {
            include("header_logged.php");
        }else{
            include("header.php");
        }
}
?>
```

Comment: maybe because `include("header.php");` is only called when $_COOKIE has values in it.

Comment: Is your error reporting enabled? Do any errors show? Is the num rows actually `>= 1`? You are setting the cookie after so that isset check will always fail.

Comment: View the real source. Is the status code of the page a 500? You are open to SQL injections. Don't store passwords as plain text, and dont store them client side.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my problem! I had made cookies instead of sessions, now I created sessions and I put the following code and it worked! But thanks to all the answers!
`

```
session_start();

if ( !isset( $_SESSION['email'] ) ) {
  include( 'header.php' );
  exit();
}else {
    if ( isset( $_SESSION['email'] ) ) {
        include( 'header_logged.php' );
        exit();
    }        
}?>`
```